# Android WebView подгрузка дополнительных JS скриптов

Tags: android, webview

Добрый день, коллеги.

Есть задача написать систему автоматизированного тестирования для web приложения с android устройств.

Сами тесты я написал на JavaScript'e теперь задача загрузить их дополнительно в WebView после загрузки необходимой страницы.

1. Собственно вопрос в том, как это сделать, без перезагрузки WebView?
2. И еще вопрос, как заставить, чтобы он при переходе по ссылке не запускал встроенный браузер а открывал все в себе?

Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: разве не лучше повешать эти тесты на сайте?

Comment: Нет, на сайте повесить не вариант.

Тестирование выполняется под все платформы (Win, nix, MacOS, iOS, Android). Написанные тесты работают под все, кроме androida, там проблема с кириллицей, точнее отправкой кириллицы через драйвер.

Comment: а чо `loadUrl()` никак?

Comment: вопрос решен как раз через loadUrl, правда появилась другая проблема.

на Andori'e в jQuery не работает click() у ссылок, придется переписывать некоторые моменты в приложении и или добавлять поддержку jQuery Modile